# EOF error when decoding json from http request

Tags: json, http, go, post, eof

I keep getting an EOF error and I'm not sure why. I have used print statements to check and the method is POST and the content-type is application/json which is to be expected.
The json I am expecting looks like this { "path": "example/path/to" }
The code runs successfully, but prints out an error which is also weird because on an error it should return before finishing the rest of the function

```
func create(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {   
     dump, er := httputil.DumpRequest(r, true)
     if er != nil {
         http.Error(w, fmt.Sprint(er), http.StatusInternalServerError)
         return
     }
     fmt.Println(string(dump)) 

     var req map[string]string
     decoder := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
     err := decoder.Decode(&req)
     if err != nil {
         fmt.Println(err)
         return
     }
     fmt.Println(req["path"])
 
     err = os.MkdirAll("/"+req["path"], os.ModePerm)
     if err != nil {
         fmt.Println(err)
         return
     }
}
```

It only prints out "Bob" and "EOF", and I've done some extensive googling but I really can't find this question answered anywhere else
I have also tried using r.ParseForm and using r.FormValue and PostFormValue, but when I do that the string is empty.

Also in case its useful, here is the front end code of value

```
fetch(url, {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({ "path": "example/path/to" })
})
```

EDIT: This is my DumpRequest

```
Listening on :5000
OPTIONS /api/create HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:5000
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Connection: keep-alive
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site

EOF
POST /api/create HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:5000
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 47
Content-Type: application/json
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Referer: http://localhost:3000/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
{"path":"/Users/paul/Desktop/temp/new/hi 2/hi"}
```

What's confusing to me is that the EOF error shows up in between the DumpRequest messages.

Comment: The `http.Request.Body` ReadCloser will return EOF immediately if it is empty. Try dumping it to make sure it really is filled with what you expect.

Comment: @Marc what exactly does dumping it mean? Is that like printing r.Body?

Comment: It means reading the body and printing it. Before trying to parse it, you should make sure you're receiving what you actually expect.

Comment: Your server code (golang) is totally fine. There seems to be a problem in javascript post object. Can you change it to { path: "example/path/to" }

Comment: Use [httputil.DumpRequest](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil/#DumpRequest) to inspect the request.

Comment: @Marc I believe I used DumpRequest correctly but let me know if there is anything else I can do. I'm definitely receiving the "path" variable correctly because the folder is being created as intended, it's just throwing a EOF file at the same time from the json decoder.

Comment: @BhupinderSinghNarang I changed it to exactly what you stated in the javascript code and still had the same EOF issue on the server code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it would seem that the issue is that my front-end is calling the endpoint twice which is why the EOF error is occurring. I wrapped all my code of my code in

```
if r.Method == "POST" {
 ...
}
```

And the issue has been resolved.

I believe that the extra endpoint hit was a CORS pre-flight thing or something.